# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы картинка background-image не обрезалась, выходя за пределы элемента?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы картинка в `background-image` не обрезалась, выходя за пределы элемента, у которого установлено это свойство?

```
<p class="background">some text</p>

.background{
  background: url("image.jpg");
}
```

То есть, чтобы `image.jpg` не обрезалась, выходя за пределы `p`?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dolphin91/0azzLswv/1/)

Comment: Уточните. Она и не выйдет за пределы.

Comment: Еще как варант задать элементу паддинг с той стороны в которую вы хотите сдвинуть картинку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кратко - нельзя.

Можно элементу `min-width` и `min-height` поставить согласно размерам картинки.

Если хотите, чтобы картинка выходила за пределы элемента, то расположите ее абсолютно в блоке.

Answer (score 1):

Ну чтобы ничего никуда не вылазило за пределы с жестко указанными размерами для div не возможно. Поскольку это обычная геометрия и ее законы. Но сделать так чтобы лишнее пряталось и размер картинки не менялся возможно.

1) Ставим картинку в сам див, или что там у вас.

```
<div class="my-some-class"><img src="/my-img.jpg" /></div>
```

2) Делаем стили блоку.

```
.my-some-class{overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

Недостаток подхода в том что width и height указывать нужно обязательно. Чтобы разместить текст над картинкой, ставим ей абсолютное позиционирование. И текст под картинку.

Comment: @Arni Извините, но я не понял, как ваш ответ относиться к моему вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Если не кратко, то можно:

```
background-size: contain
```

[Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: Прочитайте вопрос внимательно. Человек спрашивает, можно ли, чтобы картинка не обрезалась, **ВЫХОДЯ** за пределы элемента. contain просто помещает картинку в элемент

Comment: Вот она и не обрезается, а целиком и полностью показывается внутри элемента.

Comment: Да, но она ведь не выходит за пределы элементы, как хочет автор :)

Comment: Кто-то из нас явно не понял сути вопроса. Автор рассудит :)

Comment: @zhenyab Вариант с contain - это не то, что я хотел, при использовании contain размеры изображения подгоняются под размеры элемента. Мне же нужно, чтобы размер изображения не изменялся.

Comment: Судя по всему я русский подзабыл уже :(. В таком случае да, это невозможно без того, чтобы изменить хотя бы структуру HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="background">some text</p>

.background {
  position: relative;
}

.background::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: ...;
  left: ...;
  display: inline-block;
  width: ...;
  height: ...;
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
  background-repeat: ...;
  background-size: ...;
  ...
}
```

Чтобы сделать выходящее за пределы блока фоновое изображение можно использовать псевдоэлемент этого блока, которому можно будет задать необходимые размеры и позиционирование. 
Также в данном случае может быть очень полезным свойство `transform`, в частности `transform: translate()`

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае поможет CSS-свойство `background-size: cover;`